# changing in mac battery condition from service recomended to normal by updating os?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

i have 2017 macbook pro the battery condition was showing service recommended.after a while i updated my os to Big Sur and now the battery condition is normal should i be worried or its ok and i can continue using it?

Comment: macOS upgrades don't include any battery healing functionality, so it will show up as "service recommended" again sooner or later.

Comment: yeah it went back to service recommended after two week anyway thank you.@nohillside